# How can I detect when zoom in webview is changed without use of zoom controls?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a list of webviews and I need to know when the user changes the zoom level in one webview in order to apply the new zoom in other webviews.

Currently I added the OnZoomListener interface and I have `onZoom(int i)`, but it's called only when zoom is changed from zoom controls and I need to detect zoom changes when user uses fingers to change zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setLoadWithOverviewMode(boolean) loads the WebView completely zoomed out and setUseWideViewPort(boolean) makes the Webview have a normal viewport. So use these methods to evaluate.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html